# CSS Scrolling - snap into place?

Tags: html, css, vertical-scrolling, scroll-snap

I'm trying to implement vertical snap-into-place scrolling using CSS for a site, but having trouble getting it to work. To isolate the problem, I created this toy example:

```css
#container {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.tile {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:red;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:blue;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:green;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:yellow;">
  </div>
</div>
```

However everything still scrolls freely. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On all examples at MDN I have seen using scroll snapping the parent element always has a defined height and an overflow for the direction you are using, in your case `y` => `overflow-y: scroll;`. Without the defined height, in my testing the snapping will not work.

Now, since the body has the default scrolling the height must be defined in the css for body.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

#container div {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" style="">
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:red;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:blue;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:green;">
  </div>
  <div class="tile" style="background-color:yellow;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dale_landry Why the redundant `scroll-snap-type` CSS property in your code?

Comment: @PennyLiu thanks for the heads up, was an oversight, likely I forgot to remove the one without the Y Axis when I was coding.